# Como mostrar datos de Mysql en un jTextField con Java

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, netbeans

estoy creando un formulario donde al usuario se le permita crear nuevas pestañas en esta caso se llama crear nuevo horario el usuario solo ingresara su nombre y listo se creara la pestaña(horario), logre hacer el código de crear y el nombre se guarda correctamente en la base de datos y también se agrega correctamente en como una pestaña mas
Pero eso solo ocurre cuando el programa esta en ejecución cuando lo cierro y vuelvo a ejecutar ya no están las pestañas pero si en la base de datos, lo que quiero es que se muestren las pestañas ya creadas en el formulario.

Tabla de Base de Datos:

[image: Tabla de Base de Datos]

Método para registrar:

```
public boolean registrarHorario(horarios hro){
    
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = getConexion();
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO horarios (nombre) VALUES(?)";
    
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, hro.getNombre());
       
        ps.execute();
        return true;
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SqlUsuarios.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Formulario Donde estarán las pestañas creadas (Pestaña 1 lo cree manualmente insertando un jPanel)
[image: Formulario Donde estarán las pestañas creadas]

Botón Crear

```
 SqlHorarios modSql = new SqlHorarios();
    horarios mod = new horarios();
    
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa  nombre");
    mod.setNombre(name);
    if (name.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado");
    } else {
        if (modSql.registrarHorario(mod)) {
            materialTabbed3.add(name, new JPanel());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registrado");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar");
        }
        
    }
```

Lo que intente fue esto pero no me muestra nada:

```
 SqlHorarios crearSql = new SqlHorarios();
    horarios crear = new horarios();
    
     String nombre= crear.getNombre();  
    //jTextField1.setText(nombre);
    materialTabbed3.add(nombre, new JPanel());
```

Comment: ya intentaste con un select?

Comment: @RuslanLópez un select? no entiendo

Comment: si, actualmente tienes un insert, select se usa para consultar

Comment: Si ya los tengo

Comment: excelente con eso debe bastar para resolver tu problema